# Item Response Theory with GLMNET in R

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to fit the 2 Parameter Item Response Model using penalized regression as part of a project I'm working on. I've been trying to use the glmnet package in R for this purpose. The problem with doing this is that glmnet wants to penalize the parameters to zero. Instead I'd like to penalize the slope parameter such that it is penalized for moving away from one (for those familiar with IRT, I am trying to allow the data to guide whether the discrimination parameter needs to be estimated or not). Is there a way to do this in glmnet?

A similar application can be found [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1541-0420.2007.00806.x/abstract?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false).

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of packages to do IRT. If you can't make it work with `glmnet`, try a different one. You can find a list on the Psychometrics task view: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html

Answer (score 0):

This may not be as elegant as you would like, but the offset argument can do this. If you want to penalize the coefficient on (say) variable w for its deviation from 1, just add offset = w in the arguments list of your glmnet call, then add 1 to w's coefficient once the model has been fit.

If you wanted to penalize both w1 and w2's coefficients for their deviation from 1, you could add offset = w1 + w2, then add 1 to both w1 and w2's coefficients after model fit.